# Tableau using field quarterly record with monthly data

Tags: field, tableau-api, record, monthcalendar

My goal is to create a monthly employment data series given that each record has the following fields: year, quarter, and 3 monthly fields of the actual data (month 1 employment, month 2 employment, and month 3 employment).  I have to associate each month of data to an actual month (e.g., month 2 of quarter 3 in 2018 as employment for August 2018).  Each record represents a firm.  A firm will have records associated with each month.  So, looking for total employment.  There are multiple quarters and multiple years. Would I have to restructure the data or create a calculation?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using 'calculated field' easily.  Assuming your three fields are `year`, `quarter` and `month` respectively, you can create `my_month` as follows.

sample data input

```
year, quarter, month
2018, 1, 1
2018, 2, 1
2019, 4, 3
```

calculated field `my_date` as

```
MAKEDATE([Year], ([Quarter]-1)*3+[Month], 1)
```

[image: Output]

Thereafter add calculated field `Total_emp_each_month` as

```
{
Fixed [my_date] : sum([employment])
}
```